# Data Export setup changes

Tags: data-export

We have issue with export data in SF. We have weekly schedule export that take almost all the data.
But in last weeks we notice that it creating only 1 file (instead usually 3), and found that most of the objects are unchecked for export.
We sure that they was checked before. Therefore I wondering:

1.Does SF store somewhere history regarding who and when this setup was changed? (Not in audit trail for my knowledge)

2.Can be any automatic process that change this setup?

3.We had install package with many custom object that was part of the export. Now the license for this package is expired, therefore I assume it's not available for export. Possible this can cause any issue?